# x:Shared = false by default

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to set `x:Shared = false` by default somehow? I have many `ResourceDictionary` and I often forget to set it when adding new item, which can only be discovered at run-time.

---

Extra question:

[image]

Why `x:Shared` is never shown by intellisense? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't put UI elements in a ResourceDictionary to begin with.

Comment: @HighCore, what do you mean? That's vector graphics (svg -> xaml converted), I will have many and will use it (e.g. same vector icon) in multiple places, where should I keep it? Does "x:Shared" works for something else without problems?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possibility, because `x:Shared` is used in XAML only. There is no code equivalent to set it in C# code, otherwise you could have solved the problem by creating an attached property.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. I can e.g. inherit from `ResourceDictionary`, but have no idea what to do the next. Or maybe some VS extension (pre-processor) will do. I can right now solve it with some standalone or pre-build executed own-written tool, but it's too cumbersome as for me.

Comment: See paragraph starting with `Explicitly specifying x:Shared="true"` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx