# Create instance using key in the xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Given `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<GroupBox x:Key="Group"
          x:Shared="False">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    ...
    </ItemsControl>
</GroupBox>
<ItemsControl x:Key="Test"
              x:Shared="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
...
</ItemsControl>
```

Both `ItemsControl` content is identical. Is it possible to avoid duplicating  same xaml (`...` is quite big)? Is it possible to create `Test` instance from within `Group`.

Comment: Make it a UserControl.

Comment: @Clemens, clever, didn't even thought this way. Then I don't need `Key` just `<local:UserControlLalala />`. But I'd have to pass everything from *outside* (e.g. in this case `ItemsSource` binding)... not sure if long xaml is that much worse. Is there another way?

Comment: You could derive a custom control from ItemsControl and set its properties by a default Style in Generic.xaml. See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ContentControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Key="Test"
              x:Shared="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
</ItemsControl>
<GroupBox x:Key="Group" x:Shared="False">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Test}" />
</GroupBox>
```

Note that the `ItemsControl` resource must be defined before the `GroupBox` resource.

As pointed out by @grek40, you could also set the `Content` property of the `GroupBox` directly to the `ItemsSource` resource provided that the `GroupBox` doesn't contain any other controls.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can directly set the content

```
<GroupBox x:Key="Group" x:Shared="False" Content="{StaticResource Test}">
```

I'm not really a fan of `x:Shared` (bugged me some times), so how about using some DataTemplate instead?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <!-- Whatever it is you have inside... -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Yellow"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>

<GroupBox Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}">
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: I [have plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30622155/1997232) of `x:Shared`. Not sure if `DataTemplate` is better, do you have any related link? Can't find "x:Shared vs DataTemplate" or similar.

Comment: @Sinatr One of the problems of x:Shared is it's not allowed within nested `ResourceDictionary`, but I don't have a good comparison source at hand and if x:Shared works well for you, I don't need to interfere. Just wanted to add an alternative design choice to the available options with the DataTemplate approach.