# WPF Dynamic DataGrid headers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Since it is not possible to have `DataGrid` headers dynamically read some resource file, I used a method found here on SO to do so. It is working by having a `TextBlock` as a resource, which is dynamically reading some other `string` resource. Something like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource dghName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource dghAge}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and in the resources I would have this:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="dghName" Text="{DynamicResource Name}"/>
<TextBlock x:Key="dghAge" Text="{DynamicResource Age}"/>

<sys:String x:Key="Name">Name</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="Age">Age</sys:String>
```

The string resources are within some separate file and when I just swap it for some other file with the same keys but with texts on some other language, the headers are changed.

This was all working just fine, until there came a need for using the same resource on two places. I have the same `DataGrid` within two `TabItem`s. When I open the first one, the headers are shown normally, then I switch to the other tab, the headers are there as well. Now, when I change back to the first `TabItem`, the headers are empty. Same thing happens if I open the second tab first - when I switch to the first tab and then back to the second one, the headers are empty.

It would have more sense to me, if there were no headers when I open the second tab, but they are show on both tabs for the first time, and then they are gone, when I open a tab (which was the first one to open) for a second time.

The resources are within resource dictionaries, as `XAML` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [x:Shared="false"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) attribute to the elements.
This way each data grid receives it's own instance of resource instead of trying to share the same one:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="dghName" Text="{DynamicResource Name}" x:Shared="false" />
<TextBlock x:Key="dghAge" Text="{DynamicResource Age}" x:Shared="false" />
```

Comment: So easy, great!

Comment: Now to apply that to my 700+ resources xD. Find and replace will to that easily.

Comment: Do you know why this property is not visible within Intellisense?

Comment: @Adder, yeah, there seems [no other means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622155/xshared-false-by-default) to set it, so good luck with replacing :P 

As for visibility, the article about `x:Shared` states that it's strictly WPF-only. It's not in XAML specification, so I suppose that's the reason.